# memcpy vs pointers exchange?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

is there any difference between the different two ways of exchanging the contents of two arrays? (except time consumption)

```
memcpy(cells,tmp_cells,sizeof(t_speed)*params.ny*params.nx);


t_speed* temp_ptr = *cells_add;
*cells_add = *tmp_cells_add;
*tmp_cells_add = temp_ptr;
```

where

```
t_speed* cells = *cells_add; 
t_speed* tmp_cells = *tmp_cells_add;
```

Is there any potential threat on pointer exchange?

EDIT: The only thing I want to do is overwrite cells with tmp_cells :)

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of the `memcpy` you're not *exchanging* data - just copying one array to another.

Comment: @PaulR sorry for wrong description, I mean overwrites

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is the difference that if there are any other references to this array besides the ones you're swapping, they'll either point to different data (in the `memcpy` case) or to the same data (in the pointer swap case).  Which you want to do depends on your desired behaviour.

Note that your `memcpy` case just overwrites `cells`; there's no swapping going on.

Comment: oh yeah you are right, I did not notice that before. I need to overwrites cells only, is there any efficient way to do it instead of using memcpy? its too costly, cells is large and inside it there are pointers.

Comment: Swapping the pointers is fine if that's the semantics you're looking for.